# How python loads C++ shared library

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

context: I have a python program which relies on multiple libraries implemented in C++, exposed via pybinder.
My impression is: when python `import xxx`, it loads shared libraries (`.so`) into virtual memory. This is something I remember I read from book or webpage but cannot find it now.

I want to know how I can verify it in Linux? I tried to `strace` with event `open`, the only shared libraries opened are something like `py/__init__.so` (all python internal libraries), which doesn't look correct to me.

In the code base, I have multiple libcurl with multiple versions, all of them are introduced by 3-rd parties libraries. I want to know if I have a way to enforce when running python applications, they don't intervene?

For example: python program A relies on C++ shared library B and C.
B relies on libcurl (V1), statically linked.
C also relies on libcurl (V2), also statically linked.
Bad things could happen if B invokes libcurl (V2), since there might be conflict.

Comment: If they are statically linked, then there won't be any `.so` loaded.  The library is embedded into the library that's using it.  No conflict is possible.  The run-time loading of `.so`s is "dynamic" linking, the opposite of "static" linking.

Comment: A shared object (that's what the suffix `so` stands for) is loaded with [`dlopen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html). Exactly what it does I don't know, but glibc is open-source so you can look at the source to see what system calls it makes.

Comment: @TimRoberts huh, I agree with your words. jw, what if some of them is statically linked, and others are dynamically linked?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's what I think. I refer to this link (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226524/what-system-call-is-used-to-load-libraries-in-linux), and agrees with it: internally it's using open and mmap. That's the reason why `open` doesn't show any 3rd party library except python internal ones surprises me.

Comment: The names tell you what's going on.  Your application will load at runtime all the dynamically linked libraries it needs.  Some of those might need other dynamic libraries, and if so they will be found and loaded.  Statically linked libraries have no impact.  If they were needed, they were embedded when the library was built.  You will never know about them, and you will never see them.

Comment: Regarding static libraries, a static library is nothing more than an archive of object files. Linking with a static library is equivalent to linking with the individual object files. So if two (dynamic) libraries link with different versions of a static library there might be conflicts.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude For python application, all dependencies are loaded at runtime I assume?

Comment: @TimRoberts For python application, all dependencies are loaded at runtime I assume?

Comment: That's not the right way to think about it.  The Python executable probably has a number of static libraries included when the executable was built.  That's irrelevant to you.  The only dependencies loaded at runtime are the dependencies that need to be loaded at runtime.  Do you see what I mean?  If there were static libraries in use, they were all built-in at compile time.

Comment: @TimRoberts I totally agree with what you said about static library and dynamic library, and I think I understand static is "linked into main before running", and dynamic is "loaded at runtime". I understand python (the binary usually under `/usr/bin`) as a main function, when it imports, it loads what every it needs into VM. Am I understanding it wrongly?

Comment: Well, `python` doesn't do it.  The operating system's loader does it, in response to the imports table in the executable.  The loader creates a list of the libraries it needs from that table.  It runs through its list loading each one in turn.  As it loads a library, it may find MORE dynamic libraries, and it adds those to its list.  This continue until the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux systems, you can see which dynamic libraries are loaded into a process by running `cat /proc/pid/maps` where `pid` is the relevant process ID.

About your second question: If the libraries are statically linked to libcurl then they cannot use the wrong library version: the linking is static.

If the linking is dynamic then only one `libcurl` can be loaded. However `libcurl` seems to be relatively API/ABI stable so this usually wouldn't be a problem.